# Join two sets of data where data might not match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two sets of data that I would like to merge and have returned at the same time, however the column I would need to join on might have a value in set A and not in set B and vice versa, so LEFT/RIGHT JOINs are not ideal.

**Set A**

Query -

```
SELECT o.organisation_id, 
       Count(call_opened)           'opened calls',
       Format(call_opened, 'MMM-yy')'month name', 
       call_severity 
FROM   call c 
       JOIN users u 
         ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
       JOIN organisation o 
         ON o.organisation_id = u.organisation_id
WHERE  Call_Type = 'FT'
GROUP  BY o.organisation_id, 
          Format(call_opened, 'MMM-yy'), 
          call_severity
```

Returns -

```
organisation_id opened calls    month name  call_severity
BES             1               Apr-12      3
BES             1               Dec-13      3
BES             1               Jun-12      3
BES             1               Mar-12      3
BES             2               Nov-11      3
BES             1               Oct-11      3
```

**Set B**

Query -

```
SELECT o.organisation_id, 
       Count(call_closed)           'closed calls', 
       Format(call_closed, 'MMM-yy')'month name', 
       call_severity 
FROM   call c 
       JOIN users u 
         ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
       JOIN organisation o 
         ON o.organisation_id = u.organisation_id
WHERE  Call_Type = 'FT'
GROUP  BY o.organisation_id, 
          Format(call_closed, 'MMM-yy'), 
          call_severity
```

Returns -

```
organisation_id closed calls    month name  call_severity
BES             2               Aug-13      3
BES             1               Dec-11      3
BES             1               Dec-13      3
BES             1               Mar-12      3
BES             1               Nov-11      3
BES             1               Sep-12      3
```

**So Far**

Query -

```
SELECT opened.organisation_id, 
       Isnull(opened.[opened calls],0) 'opened calls',  
       Isnull(closed.[closed calls],0) 'closed calls',  
       opened.[month name], 
       opened.call_severity 
FROM   (SELECT o.organisation_id, 
               Count(call_opened)           'opened calls', 
               Format(call_opened, 'MMM-yy')'month name', 
               call_severity 
        FROM   call c 
               JOIN users u 
                 ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
               JOIN organisation o 
                 ON o.organisation_id = u.organisation_id
        WHERE  Call_Type = 'FT'
        GROUP  BY o.organisation_id, 
                  Format(call_opened, 'MMM-yy'), 
                  call_severity) opened 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT o.organisation_id, 
                         Count(call_closed)           'closed calls', 
                         Format(call_closed, 'MMM-yy')'month name', 
                         call_severity 
                  FROM   call c 
                         JOIN users u 
                           ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
                         JOIN organisation o 
                           ON o.organisation_id = u.organisation_id
                  WHERE  Call_Type = 'FT'
                  GROUP  BY o.organisation_id, 
                            Format(call_closed, 'MMM-yy'), 
                            call_severity) closed 
         ON opened.organisation_id = closed.organisation_id 
            AND opened.[month name] = closed.[month name] 
            AND opened.call_severity = closed.call_severity
WHERE opened.Call_Severity <> 5
ORDER  BY opened.organisation_id ASC
```

Returns -

```
organisation_id opened calls    closed calls    month name  call_severity
BES             1               0               Apr-12      3
BES             1               1               Dec-13      3
BES             1               0               Jun-12      3
BES             1               1               Mar-12      3
BES             2               1               Nov-11      3
BES             1               0               Oct-11      3
```

As you can see this is not returning the data I need due to Set B containing data for months that do not exist in Set A.

Ideally I would like the data to be returned like this -

```
organisation_id opened calls    closed calls    month name  call_severity
BES             1               0               Apr-12      3
BES             1               1               Dec-13      3
BES             1               0               Jun-12      3
BES             1               1               Mar-12      3
BES             2               1               Nov-11      3
BES             1               0               Oct-11      3
BES             0               2               Aug-13      3
BES             0               1               Dec-11      3
BES             0               1               Sep-12      3
```

I thought about creating an initial temp table and inserting the month values and joining the result sets on that, but that would be far too hacky and messy due to having data spanning back to 2002, is what I am after possible or do I need to rework my solution?

I think this is all the data needed from the call table -

```
Call_ID     Call_Opened                Call_Closed              Call_Severity   User_id
28000001    2011-10-19 13:13:48.000    2011-11-09 11:47:03.000  3               825
28000002    2011-11-07 10:55:24.000    2012-03-05 08:27:54.000  3               825
28000003    2011-11-21 09:11:49.000    2011-12-19 08:41:36.000  3               825
28000006    2012-03-30 15:11:23.000    2013-08-29 15:51:39.000  3               825
28000007    2012-04-02 11:50:22.000    2013-08-29 15:52:11.000  3               825
28000008    2012-06-25 08:12:39.000    2012-09-28 16:32:08.000  3               825
28000012    2013-12-17 07:41:26.000    2013-12-17 08:58:35.000  3               825
```

Comment: Those subqueries are making for quite a confusing query.I suspect, however, what you're after is a `FULL OUTER JOIN`? I would, however, consider tidying that up; I very much doubt you need 2 subqueries to achieve this. Functions like `FORMAT` are really going to affect the performance of your query too.

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN` is returning the exact same results as the `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Can you please share your 'call' table structure with possible values?

Comment: @DMayuri added data from call table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good place to use `cross apply`:

```
SELECT o.organisation_id, 
       SUM(v.is_open) as opened_calls,
       SUM(v.is_close) as closed_calls,
       Format(call_time, 'MMM-yy') as month_name, 
       call_severity 
FROM call c JOIN
     users u 
     ON u.user_id = c.user_id JOIN
     organisation o 
     ON o.organisation_id = u.organisation_id CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (call_opened, 1, 0 ), 
             (call_closed, 0, 1)
     ) as v(call_time, is_open, is_close)
WHERE Call_Type = 'FT'
GROUP BY o.organisation_id, 
         Format(call_time, 'MMM-yy'), 
         call_severity
```

Comment: are is_opened and is_closed the call_opened and call_closed columns in my call table?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint . . . No, they were typos.  They should have been qualified to be clear that they are from `VALUES()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UNION ALL` for the open call/closed call and then `group` on the top query. see the mockup below.
Let me know if you have any issue.

```
SELECT organisation_id, 
       Isnull(SUM([opened calls]),0) 'opened calls',  
       Isnull(SUM([closed calls]),0) 'closed calls',  
       [month name], 
       call_severity 
FROM   (
---Set A 
SELECT o.organisation_id, 
       Count(call_opened)           'opened calls',
       0 'closed calls',
       Format(call_opened, 'MMM-yy')'month name', 
       call_severity 
FROM   call c 
       JOIN users u 
         ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
       JOIN organisation o 
         ON o.organisation_id = u.organisation_id
WHERE  Call_Type = 'FT'
GROUP  BY o.organisation_id, 
          Format(call_opened, 'MMM-yy'), 
          call_severity


UNION ALL   ---Set B

SELECT o.organisation_id, 
       0  'opened calls',
       Count(call_closed)           'closed calls', 
       Format(call_closed, 'MMM-yy')'month name', 
       call_severity 
FROM   call c 
       JOIN users u 
         ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
       JOIN organisation o 
         ON o.organisation_id = u.organisation_id
WHERE  Call_Type = 'FT'
GROUP  BY o.organisation_id, 
          Format(call_closed, 'MMM-yy'), 
          call_severity
)S

GROUP BY
    organisation_id,
    [month name],
    call_severity
```

Comment: Your answer was good and gave me the results I needed, however I have gone for Gordons answer just on the basis that there is less code

Comment: No problem. I understand. Sometimes, it is good to have all the options. I like this method, because it is easy to debug. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Your answer will definitely be more useful to the less experienced as `CROSS APPLY` is fairly advanced

Answer (score 0):

you must use union

```
select organisation_id
, sum(opened_calls) opened_calls
, sum(closed_calls) closed_calls
, month_name 
, call_severity
from (
SELECT o.organisation_id, 
   Count(call_opened)           opened_calls,
   0                            closed_calls,
   Format(call_opened, 'MMM-yy') month_name, 
   call_severity 
FROM   call c 
   JOIN users u 
     ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
   JOIN organisation o 
     ON o.organisation_id = u.organisation_id
WHERE  Call_Type = 'FT'
GROUP  BY o.organisation_id, 
      Format(call_opened, 'MMM-yy'), 
      call_severity
union 
SELECT o.organisation_id, 
   0                            opened_calls
   Count(call_closed)           closed_calls, 
   Format(call_closed, 'MMM-yy') month_name, 
   call_severity 
FROM   call c 
   JOIN users u 
     ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
   JOIN organisation o 
     ON o.organisation_id = u.organisation_id
WHERE  Call_Type = 'FT'
GROUP  BY o.organisation_id, 
      Format(call_closed, 'MMM-yy'), 
      call_severity
)tt
group by organisation_id, month_name, call_severity
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH opened AS
(
    SELECT o.organisation_id, 
           Count(call_opened)           AS call_opened,
           Format(call_opened, 'MMM-yy') AS month_name, 
           call_severity 
    FROM   call c 
           JOIN users u 
             ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
           JOIN organisation o 
             ON o.organisation_id = u.organisation_id
    WHERE  Call_Type = 'FT'
    GROUP  BY o.organisation_id, 
              Format(call_opened, 'MMM-yy'), 
              call_severity
),
closed AS
 (
    SELECT o.organisation_id, 
           Count(call_closed)           AS call_closed, 
           Format(call_closed, 'MMM-yy') AS month_name, 
           call_severity 
    FROM   call c 
           JOIN users u 
             ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
           JOIN organisation o 
             ON o.organisation_id = u.organisation_id
    WHERE  Call_Type = 'FT'
    GROUP  BY o.organisation_id, 
              Format(call_closed, 'MMM-yy'), 
              call_severity
)
 SELECT COALESCE(opened.organisation_id, closed.organisation_id) AS organisation_id, 
 COALESCE(opened.call_opened, 0) AS call_opened, COALESCE(closed.call_closed, 0) AS call_closed, 
 COALESCE(opened.month_name, closed.month_name) AS month_name, 
 COALESCE(opened.call_severity, closed.call_severity) AS call_severity
 FROM opened 
 FULL OUTER JOIN closed 
 ON opened.month_name = closed.month_name;
```